# Vertical line in flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to figure out how to apply a vertical line that will extend all the way down between the two elements which are the sidebar and the main content. This will be my last problem in doing my website and I hope someone can help us solve my problem. I tried the border-right in my sidebar but it does not extend all the way down.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrismontage/43j1z0L8/5/

```css
/*COLOR PALETTE*/

$color1: #B87D6F;
$color2: #EBE0DD;
$color3: #FFFFFF;
$color4: #737373;
$color5: #C4B0AC;
$color6: #545454;
$color7: #A6A6A6;
$color8: #F4F4F4;
$color9: #000000;
$color10: #ebe0dd;

/*FONTS*/

$font1: Neue Montreal;
$font2: Neue Einstellung;
$font3: Maharlika;
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4B0AC;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first a {
  background-color: #ebe0dd;
  ;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #B87D6F;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.item1 {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.brand-and-desc h4 {
  font-family: $font1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #545454;
}

.status-and-price h4 {
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #545454;
}

.contact h4 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #B87D6F;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #B87D6F;
  padding: 1px 9px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contact a:hover {
  color: #A6A6A6;
}

.contact a:active {
  color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HIRAYA | Cart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/sidebar.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="line">
    </hr>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex my-4 h-100">
    <header class="sidebar">

      <div class="d-flex flex-column d-none d-md-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="my-3 first"><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Pay</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Ship</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Receive</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">Cancelled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container items-content" style="width: 80%;">
      <div class="row item1">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
          <img class="d-none d-md-block mx-3" src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" style="width: 50%;">
          <img class="my-2" src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-8 my-2 brand-and-desc">
          <h4>Charlotte Folk</span>
          </h4>
          <h4>CFXXI Sweater</h4>
          <h4>Large</h4>
          <h4>x1</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-2  my-2 status-and-price">
          <h4>To Pay</h4>
          <h4>P990</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center contact"><a href="#">
              Contact Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row item2">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
          <img class="d-none d-md-block mx-3" src="/images/homelandlogo.png" alt="" style="width: 50%;">
          <img class="my-2" src="/images/homelandproduct.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-8 my-2 brand-and-desc">
          <h4>Homeland</span>
          </h4>
          <h4>Care Reminder™ Tee Oversized Boxy Tee - Wheat</h4>
          <h4>Oversized Large</h4>
          <h4>x1</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 my-2 status-and-price">
          <h4>Completed</h4>
          <h4>P649</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center contact"><a href="#">
            Contact Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was messing around with your jsfiddle and the following seems to work.

In the HTML add `vh-100` to your `<header>` to make it the full height.

```
 <header class = "sidebar vh-100">
```

And in CSS add some quick code for the border of `<header>` like you tried before.

```
.sidebar{
border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Last question, how will I remove the border-right when I will be in mobile version? because it seems there is still a border even though I set it as d-none d-md-block. Im trying my page to be responsive hehe

Comment: @Chris Add the class to the same element which has the `d-none`. See my solution.

Comment: Hi again Chris, I recommend making a new question as it's the best way to do things around here but to give you a head start. You can use `@media` queries in your CSS to switch HTML items on or off for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of making semantic errors in your markup. I noticed there were some spacing issues and random closing `</span>` tags in your HTML.

With that being said, you can add `vh-100` class to your `.sidebar` for it to stand the entire viewport height and add the `border-right` styles following that. You can then using `padding` to separate the `border` from the `ul`.

```css
/*COLOR PALETTE*/

$color1: #B87D6F;
$color2: #EBE0DD;
$color3: #FFFFFF;
$color4: #737373;
$color5: #C4B0AC;
$color6: #545454;
$color7: #A6A6A6;
$color8: #F4F4F4;
$color9: #000000;
$color10: #ebe0dd;

/*FONTS*/

$font1: Neue Montreal;
$font2: Neue Einstellung;
$font3: Maharlika;
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4B0AC;
}

.sidebar {
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first a {
  background-color: #ebe0dd;
  ;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #B87D6F;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.item1 {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.brand-and-desc h4 {
  font-family: $font1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #545454;
}

.status-and-price h4 {
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #545454;
}

.contact h4 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #B87D6F;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #B87D6F;
  padding: 1px 9px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Neue Montreal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contact a:hover {
  color: #A6A6A6;
}

.contact a:active {
  color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HIRAYA | Cart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/sidebar.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="d-flex my-4 h-100">
    <header class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column d-none d-md-block vh-100 sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li class="my-3 first"><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Pay</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Ship</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">To Receive</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
          <li class="my-3"><a href="#">Cancelled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container items-content" style="width: 80%;">
      <div class="row item1">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
          <img class="d-none d-md-block mx-3" src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" style="width: 50%;">
          <img class="my-2" src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-8 my-2 brand-and-desc">
          <h4>Charlotte Folk</h4>
          <h4>CFXXI Sweater</h4>
          <h4>Large</h4>
          <h4>x1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2  my-2 status-and-price">
          <h4>To Pay</h4>
          <h4>P990</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center contact"><a href="#">
              Contact Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row item2">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
          <img class="d-none d-md-block mx-3" src="/images/homelandlogo.png" alt="" style="width: 50%;">
          <img class="my-2" src="/images/homelandproduct.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-8 my-2 brand-and-desc">
          <h4>Homeland</h4>
          <h4>Care Reminder™ Tee Oversized Boxy Tee - Wheat</h4>
          <h4>Oversized Large</h4>
          <h4>x1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-md-2 my-2 status-and-price">
          <h4>Completed</h4>
          <h4>P649</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center contact"><a href="#">
            Contact Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```